# How can I consolidate a SQL query as an integer?

Tags: mysql, sql

The following SQL (PHP, MySQL) gives me rows with one id per row and the number of matches for each id, as the `COUNT()` for each.

```
SELECT ot.id, COUNT(ot.id) 
FROM ot 
JOIN tm on tm.mediaid = ot.id 
WHERE tm.uploadedToS3 = 1 
    AND (
        ot.something IN (1) 
        OR ot.somethingelse IN (1) 
        OR ot.anotherthing IN (1) 
        OR ot.morestuff IN (1) 
        OR ot.evenmorestuff IN (1) 
    ) 
GROUP BY ot.id
```

The result is something like...

```
ot.id COUNT(ot.id)
40153 4
40305 3
40309 35
40314 29
40315 12
40317 10
40318 16
40319 14
40324 154
40331 113
```

I would just like to know how many rows this query returns. I don't need any other information, just one integer. For the above, I am looking for the number of rows, i.e. I'd expect to just get the number 10.

How would I get this?

Thanks.

Comment: `select count(*) from (<your query>) t`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `count(distinct)` with no `group by`:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ot.id)
FROM ot JOIN
     tm 
     ON tm.mediaid = ot.id 
WHERE tm.uploadedToS3 = 1 AND
      (ot.something IN (1) 
        OR ot.somethingelseIN (1) 
        OR ot.anotherthing IN (1) 
        OR ot.morestuff IN (1) 
        OR ot.evenmorestuff IN (1) 
      )
```